# Unable to pass deep links with parameters - Android

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am trying to pass parameters to deep links in Android and that is not working.

I have specified a `hostName` variable in the `app/build.gradle` file to distinguish between UAT and production URLs. This `hostName` variable is referenced in `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- deep links for home page. -->
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="${hostName}"
                    android:pathPrefix="/login.jsp?signup=true" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I am trying to use `adb` to test for deep links like so:
`adb.exe shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.mywebsite.co.in/login.jsp?signup=true" com.myapp.ui.MyActivity`

The error I get is:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.mywebsite.co.in/... pkg=com.myapp.android.alpha }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.mywebsite.co.in/... flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.myapp.android.alpha }
```

I have read through a number of similar questions here on SO and all of them suggest escaping the special characters. But that has not worked in this case.

Any insights on resolving this will be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The `android:pathPrefix` is invalid in your AndroidManifest.xml.
It should only contain the path element, not the query:

```
android:pathPrefix="/login.jsp"
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want it to contain the query? Also, if I put only the path element, does that mean all queries are also automatically deep linked?

Comment: Yes, there is currently no support for query filtering in intent-filter. But you can filter them when receiveing the deeplink, and if it doesn't match you can programmatically re-send the intent (and remove your package from the potential intent receivers).

Answer (score 0):

The query string `?signup=true` is not part of the path. You cannot filter on query strings.